# How to get the first business day in a new month after the weekend?

Tags: matlab, datetime, weekday

How can I in a smart way get the first business day of a month after the weekend?

To get the first business day of the month (given `dateInput`), we can do:

```
firstBusdayMonth = fbusdate(year(dateInput),month(dateInput));
```

As an example, for November, using the above function will return Thursday November 1 as the first business day. However, the first business day of the month **after the first weekend** is Monday November 5. How can I get this latter date?

[image]

Notes:

- The weekend does not have to be in the same month.
- If the Monday is not a working day, then I would like it to return the next business day

Comment: Why is Thursday, November 1 not considered a working day by you? And I guess you mean Monday, November 5.?

Comment: He want first working day after weekend

Comment: It is a working day, but I am looking for the first business day after the first weekend of the month.

Comment: @Adriaan Can you please clarify? How can my question be that unclear?

Comment: check for the day in your returned value, if it's not monday then add "Number of Days" that make it Monday.

Comment: @JohnAndrews you can simply get the First Monday of the Month. I guess that will be enough

Comment: That is the tricky part indeed, the weekend does not have to be per se in the same month. It can be indeed end of December and then the first Monday of the month, if it is a business day, would be the 1st of January. However, if the 1st is a holiday then I need to get the Tuesday the 2nd (which is a business day).

Comment: Rough outline I'd try: check the first of the month, whether it's a Monday and if so, not a public holiday. If not, get the first Monday in the month (I'd simply step a maximum of 7 times), and if found, again do the holiday check. If a holiday checks out on any found Monday, get the next day; perhaps recursively check in case your country allows for consecutive Monday-Tuesday holidays (e.g. Christmas, although that's not in the beginning of the month). The financial toolbox allows for business-day checks; whether a day is a Monday is left as exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will do the trick. Here is the logic:

- Create a datetime array for all days in the given month.
- Get the day numbers.
- Create a logical array, true from the first Monday onwards (so after the first weekend, accounting for the last day of the previous month being a Sunday).
- Create another logical array using `isbusday` to exclude Mondays which aren't working days.
- Finding the first day number where these two logical arrays are true, therefore the first business day after the weekend.

Code:

```
function d = fbusdateAferWE( y, m )
    % Inputs: y = year, m = month
    % Outputs: day of the month, first business day after weekend

    % Create array of days for the given month
    dates = datetime( y, m, 1 ):days(1):datetime( y, m, eomday( y, m ) );
    % Get the weekday numbers to find first Monday, 1 = Sunday
    dayNum = weekday( dates );                   
    % Create the logical array to determine days from first Monday
    afterFirstWeekend = ( cumsum(dayNum==2) > 0 ).'; 
    % Get first day which is afterFirstWeekend and a business day.
    d = find( afterFirstWeekend & isbusday( dates ), 1 );    
end
```

You could probably speed this up (although it will be pretty rapid already) by not looking at the whole month, but say just 2 weeks. I used `eomday` to get the last day of the month, which means I don't have to make assumptions about a low number of holiday days in the first week or anything.

---

**Edit:** Working with `datenum` speeds it up by half (C/O JohnAndrews):

```
function d = fbusdateAferWE( y, m )
    % Inputs: y = year, m = month
    % Outputs: day of the month, first business day after weekend

    % Create array of days for (first 2 weeks of) the given month
    dates = datenum(datetime(y,m,1)):datenum(datetime(y,m,eomday(y,m)))-14;        
    % Get the weekday numbers to find first Monday, 1 = Sunday
    dayNum = weekday( dates );         
    % Create the logical array to determine days from first Monday
    afterFirstWeekend = ( cumsum(dayNum==2) > 0 ).';         
    % Get first day which is afterFirstWeekend and a business day.
    d = find( afterFirstWeekend & isbusday( dates ), 1 );    
end
```

Comment: `eomday-14` should suffice already for the speed-up I think, that'll look at the first 2 weeks, which should be sufficient, barring week-long holiday practises if present in some countries

Comment: @Adriaan This is of order 0.01secs on my machine, so going from ~30 elements to ~15 isn't really worth the effort. Easier just to not make the assumptions unless this is getting called thousands of times :)

Comment: Seems like a promising solution in terms of outcome, but speed indeed is something that I'll need to improve. As a comparison, the function fbusdate(y,m) takes +-1.04 seconds to evaluate on a datenum vector of 4958, whereas fbusdateAfterWE takes +-7.95 seconds.

Comment: @John you *might* find that looping through the month day-by-day to implement the same logic is quicker. Loops aren't inherently slow in MATLAB, and I'm doing more expensive calls to `weekday` and `isbusday` because of the surplus days. You can then break from the loop when you hit the first satisfactory day.

Comment: @John r.e. your edit, I accepted it because the speed improvement is significant, but I changed the output to be the day number. I think it's more cohesive to maintain the data types between input and output. If your specific application requires the additional `datenum` conversion then feel free to keep in! Simply returning the day is of course slightly quicker as we avoid an extra type conversion :)

Answer (score -1):

I would add something like this after your statement:

```
[DayNumber, DayName] = weekday(firstBusdayMonth);
if DayNumber > 2
    day = 10 - DayNumber;
else
```

This works because 'weekday' will return a number between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday).

The fbusdate() function will never return a 1 or 7, so we can ignore those cases.

If weekday(fbusdate()) == 2, the first is on a Monday and the firstBusdayMonth variable doesn't need to be changed.

If weekday(firstBusdayMonth) returns between 2 and 6, we need to skip to the next week, so we subtract the weekday value from 10 to find the next Monday.

It might not be the *most* elegant solution, but should work.

Comment: This is incorrect; if e.g. 1st January is a Monday, 2nd January would be the one to catch, not 8th January, which is what this would give. This script finds the first **Monday which is a business day**, not the first business day after a weekend in a month. The check needs to be recursive as well; e.g. 5th May is a holiday in the Netherlands, if that's a Monday and Pentecost boxingday is the 12th, that's not a business day, although this code would say it is.